# I'm unable to get a type using the Type.GetType method?

Tags: c#

Sorry if the question sounds confusing. My problem is that I am using the following:

```
var packageType = Type.GetType(className);
```

I have checked very carefully that className is the fully qualified name of a type. I checked the className variable many times. But still when this is executed it gives packageType as null !

I know my class name is Product.  Is there a way that I can get a string representation of the name so I can check to see if it compares exactly with the className string I am passing to the above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need to provide the **assembly qualified name**. Note:

[Type.GetType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx)

> Parameters: typeName
>
> Type: System.String
>
> The assembly-qualified name of the type to get. See [AssemblyQualifiedName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname.aspx). If the type is in the currently executing assembly or in Mscorlib.dll, it is sufficient to supply the type name qualified by its namespace.

For example, if I am trying to get a type defined outside of the currently executing assembly, I could use `Type.GetType` as following:

```
var name = "CommonLibrary.ICommand, CommonLibrary, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null";
var type = Type.GetType(name);
```

If inside the executing assembly, I only need to qualify it via the namespace

```
var type = Type.GetType("CommonLibrary.ICommand");
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes: `typeof(Product).FullName`

Answer (score -1):

You need to call this using an object e.g.

```
string str = "";
string type = str.GetType().ToString();
```

This will give you "System.String" in "type" variable

Comment: That's only if you want to get the type of an object. What if there's no object?