# Type.GetType() throwing null exception

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am trying to get the type of a class by calling Type.GetType(), however it is throwing an null reference exception. I'm supplying the fully qualified name of the class as a string, I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. Here is what I am doing:

```
Type.GetType("The.Name.Space.TheClassName")
```

That is the fully qualified name of the class, it works fine for import statements. Could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? Any suggestions would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Edit: code block

Comment: You likely need the [assembly qualified name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8681305/im-unable-to-get-a-type-using-the-type-gettype-method/8681446#8681446). Without it, the type must be in the currently executing assembly or in mscorlib.dll, otherwise GetType returns null (as it will not find the class).

Comment: Maybe try using `System.Type` to assure you're not referring to a more local method or property called `Type`

Comment: Be careful: I very much doubt that `Type.GetType` is throwing an exception itself - but it may well be returning a null reference. They're very different things.

Comment: Yea, I took the question to mean the call itself was throwing an exception which led me to believe they were not actually calling `System.Type.GetType()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to supply an [AssemblyQualifiedName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname.aspx) for `Type.GetType()`. [Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/haibo_luo/archive/2005/08/21/454213.aspx)'s an interesting blog post about several caveats of using `Type.GetType()`.

Answer (score 6):

If the type you are after isn't in System/mscorlib, and isn't in the calling assembly, then you should use an assembly-qualified name, for example:

```
Type type = Type.GetType(
    "The.Name.Space.TheClassName, The.Assembly")
```

Comment: var type = Type.GetType("System.Data.DBConcurrencyException, System.Data"); not working. Any Idea why?